# Threejs WebGLRenderTarget return different texture result with render to screen

Tags: three.js

The code

```
var renderTargetParameters = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: false,depthBuffer:false },
        renderTargetOcl = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( SCREEN_WIDTH/4, SCREEN_HEIGHT/4, renderTargetParameters );

    var effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras[ "fxaa" ] );
    effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / SCREEN_WIDTH, 1 / SCREEN_HEIGHT );

    let hblur = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras[ "horizontalBlur" ] );
    let vblur = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras[ "verticalBlur" ] );

    var bluriness = 2;

    hblur.uniforms[ 'h' ].value = bluriness / SCREEN_WIDTH*2;
    vblur.uniforms[ 'v' ].value = bluriness / SCREEN_HEIGHT*2;

    var renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass( this.scene, this.camera );
    var renderModelOcl = new THREE.RenderPass( this.oclscene, this.oclcamera );

    let grPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras['Godrays'] );
    grPass.needsSwap = true;
    grPass.renderToScreen = false;

    var finalPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras['Additive'] );
    finalPass.needsSwap = true;
    finalPass.renderToScreen = true;

    let oclcomposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( this.renderer, renderTargetOcl );

    oclcomposer.addPass( renderModelOcl );
    oclcomposer.addPass( hblur );
    oclcomposer.addPass( vblur );
    oclcomposer.addPass( hblur );
    oclcomposer.addPass( vblur );
    oclcomposer.addPass( grPass );



    let renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters );

    let finalcomposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( this.renderer, renderTarget );

    finalcomposer.addPass( renderModel );
    // finalcomposer.addPass( effectFXAA );
    finalcomposer.addPass( finalPass );

    finalPass.uniforms[ 'tAdd' ].value = oclcomposer.renderTarget1.texture;
```

I'm trying to make light scrattring.

When set grPass.renderToScreen = true; and finalPass.renderToScreen = false; i got right result.That means the first composer works well.

While i use the oclcomposer as texture to a plane material ,it get wrong result:the light keeps shinning and has green and yellow ring aroud it.

The result i want is like:[image],not shinning all the time and only has blue color.The wrong result disappears once i cut the screen.

From above,i think that's from the rendertarget which get wrong result,has no idea what it changes the texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,when i set grPass.needsSwap = false it works.Seem like an version change.